# Strict Value Comparison (less/greater than)

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm pretty sure that the following behaves incorrectly (at least, in my mind) because of some truthiness craziness:

```
var x = 5;
0 < x < 10 // True, and returns true.
0 < x < 2 // False, and returns true.
0 < x < 0 // False, and returns false.
```

The way I figure it, the (0 < 5) is evaluating to true, and (true < 2) is also evaluating to true (i.e., 1 < 2). I tested this with the third statement, which seems to confirm my theory. Now to the question: is there any way to make this 'work' without large amounts of extra code?

Comment: If you are using this in a conditional statement, why not use `0 < x && x < 2`?

Comment: Three people in less than a minute ... well, I guess I can safely award myself the 'dumb question asked' achievement.

Comment: as am not i am said use the && to join comparisons together instead of chaining them like that. The 2nd one returns true because 5 > 0 evaluates to true, and then through javascript funkiness that lets you compare a boolean and a number, true < 2 and hence the whole thing returns true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *"...is there any way to make this 'work' without large amounts of extra code?"*

Sure, use `&&`...

```
(0 < x) && (x < 10)
```

You can drop the parentheses if you want.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed most programming languages will not implement "between" as you would write it mathematically. Instead separate the comparisons into two, where only two elements are compared each time.

```
var x = 5;
0 < x && x < 10
0 < x && x < 2
0 < x && x < 2
```

So, the first line reads "zero is less than x and x is less than ten". If you are uncertain about in which order the expression will be evaluated, will work as grouping.

```
(0 < x) && (x < 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that < is a binary operator.

Which means that one of the < gets evaluated at a time, not both.

Which means that regardless of the order in which they are evaluated (which, IIRC is L to R), one of the comparisons will be wrong.

Because this is CODE.

Not ALGEBRA.

Otherwise, clever use of the && operator, as discussed by other answers, will make short work of your problem.

Comment: In fact, it is left to right. In fact, I said as much :| but thank you for internet yelling at me.